# Which is appropriate: First to understand OR to first understand

Tags: prepositional-phrases

I am writing an article on Psychology and stumbled across the following choices:

1- To begin with child psychology, it is important *first to understand* what psychology *all about is*.

2- To begin with child psychology, it is important *to first understand* what psychology *all about is*.

3- To begin with child psychology, it is important *first  to  understand* what psychology *is all about*.

4- To begin with child psychology, it is important *to first understand* what psychology *is all about*.

Which  of the above sentences is most appropriate?   I have *italicized*  the phrases which are confusing to me.   Also do I need a question mark or a period at the end ?

Comment: Option 1 and 2 are incorrect. Option 3 is preferable to me. I think option 4 contains a split infinitive and although these aren’t "illegal", they are frowned upon.

Comment: @Pam Thanks for your comment. please explain why do you think 1 and 2 are incorrect and 4 is not very good. Could you please give an answer instead of the comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is a "usage" rather than a "language" question. Technically 1 + 2 have something the others don't as they avoid ending the sentence with a preposition, but that structure will look odd to anyone accustomed to reading or speaking English - unless Yoda you are.

Interestingly, the answer that will look most natural to a large number of native English speakers has both a preposition at the end and a split infinitive (number 4), though number 3 also works.

Full stop (period) at the end. It's a statement rather than a question in all four cases.

Answer (score -1):

1& #2 are so bad I assume they are put there to broaden the argument. #3 Does not have the split infinitive but #4 is the clearest.